# Map that automatically zooms out

Tags: software-recommendations, zoom, mapping

Suppose I have an online store in San Francisco, California. Most of my customers are from the Bay Area, but I do have some customers from the rest of the U.S.

For my analytics platform, I want to build a map that initially shows my customers in the Bay Area (one dot for each customer at their residential address). Then it will gradually and continuously zoom out to show all the customers in the entire U.S.

When it has completely zoomed out, the center of the map should be the center of the U.S. (usually thought to be in Kansas).

What software can I use for this?

I don't mind coding something up from scratch (e.g. from Javascript) if there isn't anything prebuilt in other software packages e.g. ArcGIS.

Comment: I'd probably use JS for this. Apparently Leaflet has a 'flyTo' method which can animate both pan and zoom, as per [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36167900/5158630). Not tried it myself though.

Comment: To make this not be asking the community to develop you a list of candidate software you could instead describe the functionality that you seek (which you have) and ask what that functionality is called. Armed with that you can search for software that supports it.

Comment: Leaflet JavaScript library (https://leafletjs.com/) is definitely the simplest way to go and it covers all your described needs too.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that almost all mature JS mapping libraries have this capability. In the case of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript I would take a look at the [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html) class and the [`goTo()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#goTo) method.

If you check their examples you will see that its pretty straightforward and does exactly what you are asking for.

```
var pt = new Point({
  latitude: 49,
  longitude: -126
});

var opts = {
  duration: 5000  // Duration of animation will be 5 seconds
};

// go to point at LOD 15 with custom duration
view.goTo({
  target: pt,
  zoom: 15
}, opts);

// go to the given point
view.goTo(pt);
```

Take a look at the documentation because there are several options you can configure.